# How to understand the usage of Inner and Outer figuratively?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, inner

### Description:

In *Mathematica* the functions like `Thread`, `Inner`, `Outer` etc. are very important and are used frequently.

For the function `Thread`:

Thread Usage1:

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}]]
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c]}
> ```

Thread Usage2:

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, x]]
```

> ```
> {f[a, x], f[b, x], f[c, x]}
> ```

Thread Usage3:

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
```

> ```
> {f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]}
> ```

And I understand the `Usage1`, `Usage2`, `Usage3` easily as well as I use them masterly.

However I always cannot master the usage of **`Inner`** and **`Outer`** so that I must refer to the *Mathematica* Documentation every time when I feel I need using them.

I find that I cannot master them owing to that I cannot understand the results of **`Inner`** and **`Outer`** clearly. Namely, I always forget what construct they generate when executed.

The typical usage cases of `Inner` and `Outer` shown as below:

---

**Inner Usage**:

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {x, y}, g]
```

> ```
> g[f[a, x], f[b, y]]
> ```

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {x, y}, g]
```

> ```
> {g[f[a, x], f[b, y]], g[f[c, x], f[d, y]]}
> ```

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{x, y}, {u, v}}, g]
```

> ```
> {{g[f[a, x], f[b, u]], g[f[a, y], f[b, v]]}, 
>  {g[f[c, x], f[d, u]], g[f[c, y], f[d, v]]}}
> ```

**Outer Usage**:

```
Outer[f, {a, b}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z]}, {f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z]}}
> ```

```
Outer[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> ```
> {{{{f[1, a], f[1, b]}, {f[1, c], f[1, d]}}, 
>   {{f[2, a], f[2, b]}, {f[2, c], f[2, d]}}}, 
>  {{{f[3, a], f[3, b]}, {f[3, c], f[3, d]}}, 
>   {{f[4, a], f[4, b]}, {f[4, c], f[4, d]}}}}
> ```

### Questions:

1. How to master the usage **`Inner`** and **`Outer`**? Namely, how can I use them without referring to the *Mathematica* Documentation?
2. How to understand the result of `Out[3]`,`Out[4]`,`Out[5]` figuratively? Namely, by using graphics or other way.

Comment: I recommend that you download and work through Leonid Shifrin's [Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/). It's free and answers a lot of question you ask.

Comment: I don't know why you are leaving.  All I can say is that I hope you are not taking SE too seriously.  It's just a website, a tool to get help and learn from.  When you find yourself spending too much time on it, it's good to take a break.  I do that from time to time.  But don't let it affect you emotionally.

Comment: @Szabolcs  In fact, I made a mistake and Moderator R.M pointed it out some time ago. And I did affected by M.SE emotionly but I don't know why.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think of `Outer` just like nikie [showed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57767/9391).

`Inner` is a generalization of matrix multiplication. I like the picture from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) page.

[image: Matrix Multiplication]

To calculate an entry of matrix multiplication, you first pair list entries (a11,b12) and (a12,b22). You "times/multiply" those pairs (a11*b12) and (a12*b22), and then you "plus/add" all the results (a11*b12)+(a12*b22). Note that you "times" before you "plus" in matrix multiplication which helps me remember the order of arguments for `Inner`.

```
listL={{a11,a12},{a21,a22},{a31,a32},{a41,a42}};
listR={{b11,b12,b13},{b21,b22,b23}};
Inner[times,listL,listR,plus]
```

Answer (score 46):

[Animated Mathematica Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/) contains cool animated illustrations of the way a number of built-in functions work. Among them are

[Thread](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Thread.html)

[image]

[Inner](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Inner.html):

[image]

[Outer](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Outer.html)

[image]

See also: [cormullion's video](http://vimeo.com/76809340)

Comment: @kguler...I am learning so much this week...nice

Comment: Loved them when they first came out; still love them today.

Comment: @J. M., same here -- especially the sound effects:)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., I know you are J.M :) Welcome back!

Comment: @Leandro I am not sure why you are addressing me here.  This is kglr's answer, not mine; I only edited it.  Also the answer starts with a link to a collection of these animations: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/

Answer (score 25):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for: This is the image I always have in mind for `Outer[f,{a,b,c},{x,y,z}]`:

[image]

```
args = {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}};
TableForm[Outer[f, args[[1]], args[[2]]], TableHeadings -> args]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
(i = Inner[List, Range@3, Range@3, List]) // MatrixForm;
```

[image]

```
(o = Outer[List, Range@3, Range@3]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[i, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];
p2 = ListLinePlot[o, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];

Legended[Show[p2, p1, PlotRange -> All], LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Inner", "Outer"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: like you answer+1

Comment: +1 for the compactness. It might have been even more immediate (specially in the first example) with:  (i = Inner[List, {a, b, c}, Range@3, List]) // MatrixForm.

Answer (score 9):

I think of `Outer` like [nikie's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/nikie) answer shows.  Here's a similar view of `Inner`.  Think of the arguments in columns.  Apply `f` to each row and `g` to the result.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
args = {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}};
Format[g[e__]] := Column[{g, e},
   Dividers -> {None, {False, True, False}}, Alignment -> Center];
Inner[f, Sequence @@ args, g]
```

Comment: Might I suggest `f@@{a,x}` etc.?

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted a divider, but I hate dealing with tables/grids in *Mma*.  I'd thought about `f[a, x]`, too (i.e., no `Format`-ting).  I was trying to emphasize the columns.